# How can I find and overwrite the keybinding to CREATE FOLDER in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VSCode documentation says:

> Keyboard Shortcut: ctrl+alt+N to create new files & ctrl+alt+shift+N to create new folders. (you can override these shortcuts).

I can't find those

I found 
`{ "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" }`

But nothing regarding `newFolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a keybinding for `explorer.newFolder` (no keybinding by default).

You can do it via GUI: File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts